# Linux: Are there pitfalls, when saving a whole device unsing "dd"?

Tags: linux, backup, dd

I have extensive changes on my data coming up and I want to backup the current disk.

Is the following procedure correct, i.e. is it unlikely that somehow I can't use the diskdump later on to backup my data from that dump?

1) boot via USB Stick (there is aubuntu running from the USB stick)

2) source and destination (1st partition of sda and sdb) have been mounted automatically.

3) `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/sdb1/dump.file bs=1000MB`

If you see anything that could cause errors later on (when doing the reverse thing), please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

dd is a bit copy. you would need to do the whole partition and backup to the same size and geometry.

for backup you can use.
"cp -a" recursively copies, 
"cpio " copies and also is able to work with devices.
"tar -czf"  backs up and compresses.

Comment: yes, for simplicity I'd actually like a bitwise copy. I'm copying the device to a file on a larger dervice. Then later (if errors occurred) I want to copy the content of that file back on the source device.